# Change selected range with value/text entered in a inputbox

Tags: excel, vba

How do I set my own range and not be limited to column BB?

So what I would like to do is select a range, then the inputbox should pop-up so I can enter a value or text so the selected range gets replace with the value/etxt entered in the inputbox.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
   Dim Pcode As String
   Dim Fnd As Range
   
   Pcode = InputBox("Give Value")
   Set Fnd = Range("1:1").Find("Value Changed", , , xlWhole, , , False, , False)
   If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
      Fnd.Offset(1).Resize(Range("BB" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1).Value = Pcode
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot see any "selected range" in your code. Do you want saying only the defined range? Which is the problem of the code you use? Are there in the first row a cell with "Value Changed" value? Do you really need to set the last row of the "BB:BB" column, or "B:B"? Does your code return any error? Does it reach the part `Fnd.Offset(1).Resize(`?

Comment: And what's the logic behind for doing that? Isn't it better to use just the input?

Comment: Right now I can only replace the values/text in column BB with header Value Changed, but I would like to select my own column or range to use the inputbox to change the values or text in a certain column.

Comment: This is what you should state in your question... You simple place "Value Changed" in another column, but the range to be processed is calculated according to BB:BB last cel. Are there different numbers of rows in the involved column and you want using the header matching one?

Comment: No it can be any column, I'm just looking for a solution where I can select any cell or column and enter the given data entered in the inputbox.

Comment: If so, why did you try that pseudo code searching for a column Header?

Comment: It was my first attempt, it worked but it needed to change to what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it already!

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    Dim Pcode As String
    Dim selectedRng As Range
    Set selectedRng = Application.Selection
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Set selectedRng = Application.InputBox("Range", , selectedRng.Address, Type:=8)
       Pcode = InputBox("Give Value")
       selectedRng.Value = Pcode
    Exit Sub
    errHandler:
    If Err.Number = 424 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else: MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number, vbOK
    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the involved columns have different number of rows and you need the calculate the last cell on the matched column, please use the next code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
   Dim Pcode As String, Fnd As Range
   
   Pcode = InputBox("Give Value")
   If Pcode = "" Then Exit Sub
   Set Fnd = Range("1:1").Find("Value Changed", , , xlWhole, , , False, , False)
   If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
      Fnd.Offset(1).Resize(cells(1, Fnd.column).End(xlUp).row - 1).Value = Pcode
   End If
End Sub
```